# System.Web.Mvc version not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I receive the following error after compiling my MVC app.

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   HNZPartsExtract.PHAWeb.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in d:\test\CCA GMOV\HNZPartsExtract\HZAPartsExtract.PHAWeb\Global.asax.cs:19

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12601341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618388
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458005
```

I have version 4.0 added as a reference, so I'm not sure why I receive that error. I do not have 5.2, but it looks like I need 5.2.. However, I'm unable to install NuGet packages in my current development environment so I'm not sure how I can just download that dll and add it without NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already try this? Copy Local = True

[image: Did you already try this?]

Answer (score 1):

If the project started in VS2013, the default template references MVC5, so even if you add an assembly reference to the 4.0 binaries, your web.config(s) still reference 5.x (with x representing whatever was current when the project was created).

You can download the MVC package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/ and then unpack the .nupkg archive (using 7zip or similar) to get at the .dll file.

If your reason for not using NuGet is because you're using an older Express Edition that doesn't have NuGet support, upgrade to the Community Edition. Assuming you have the most recent WPI (Web Platform Installer), it's listed under the Tools section, or you can download it from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx.

Comment: I actually don't see a way to download it from there. That's been my issue. I only see the option to download it with Package Manager which does not currently work in my limited development environment because it reaches outside of our intranet. I was looking for a way to download it locally and then add it over to the project in the dev environment.

Comment: The Download link downloads a .nuspec file. Save it to disk somewhere, and then use something like 7zip to extract the file to a folder. Within that folder you will find the System.Web.Mvc.dll

Comment: Sigh.. the original link I clicked to take me to that page said "Download" which confused me, so I figured clicking "Download" again would do the same thing. I derped hard.. Thanks.

Comment: If the problem is a [pointy-haired boss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss) that doesn't trust NuGet, you can always suggest a hosted service like [MyGet](http://www.myget.org/), which can be used (in part) to create a feed of "sanctioned" packages, like the System.Web.Mvc package.